# Login with Amazon LWA

Tags: android, login-with-amazon

Hi All i have a requirement like login through Amazon LWA.
I followed there [official document.](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/register-android.html)

I did all steps and cross checked.
After run the app i am getting the following error.

```
com.android.amazon.myapplicationamazon W/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder: Failed to decode: Decoding failed: certificate fingerprint can't be verified! 
com.android.amazon.myapplicationamazon W/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder: Unable to decode APIKey
```

I am googling a lot.But I didn't find the solution.

If anybody know the solution.Can you please help me.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use the exact same credentials in app/build.gradle signingConfigs
to create the credentials for login with amazon api key 
use this to get the MD5 and SHA256

```
keytool -list -v -alias <alias> -keystore <keystore.filename>
```